# Spark Machine Learning running on a single machine: Is it distributed or not?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Recently I'm learning scalable machine learning and Spark MLlib is the first tool I learned to use. I have already succeeded to implement some simple machine learning tasks such as linear regression with Spark MLlib, and they all run smoothly on my laptop.

However, I'm wondering, the program is not deployed on a cluster, and it's running on a single node. Is it still not distributed in this kind of scenario. If it's distributed, does Spark automatically run tasks with multi-threads?

Can anybody tell me the reason why Spark MLlib makes scalable machine learning implementation easier?

Comment: if your single node has multiple cores, the tasks might be distributed across those cores by `local[*]` option which automatically detects the number of cores

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what your definition of "distributed" is.

Spark MLlib is a framework that allows (but not guarantees) you to write code that is **capable** of being distributed. It handles a lot of the distribution and synchronisation issues that come with distributed computing. So yes, it makes it much simpler for programmers to code and deploy distributed algorithms.

The reason why Spark makes scalable ML easier is because you can focus more on the algorithm, rather than being bogged down by data races and how to distribute code to different nodes, taking into account data locality etc. All of that is typically handled by the SparkContext / RDD class.

That being said, coding for Spark does not guarantee that it **will** be distributed optimally. There are still things to consider like data partitioning and level of parallelism, among many others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I just run a simple linear regression on my laptop without creating any threads, is it the same as writing the algorithm in simple python skit-learn from the distributed perspective?

Comment: If you're using Spark, it's likely that you already *are* creating threads. This depends on your `.setMaster("local[*]")`. The asterisk means you want to use all logical cores, probably 4/8/12 depending on what your laptop has. As for scikit-learn, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51318367/scikit-learn-multithreading

If you do use multithread in scikit-learn, then both methods are parallel processing, but not distributed. You may want to see http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/distributed-vs-parallel-computing