# Run Scikit-learn fit and prediction in multithreading in julia

Tags: multithreading, scikit-learn, julia

I was wondering if it is possible to run a scikit-learn model's fit and prediction fucntion on multithreading in julia.

For Example:

```
using ScikitLearn
@sk_import linear_model: LogisticRegression

# Fit the model
log_reg = fit!(LogisticRegression(), X_train, y_train)

# Predict on the test set
sklearn_pred = log_reg.predict(X_test)
```

This above code is using PyCall to access Scikit-learn model in python and if I am not wrong the SkLearn model by default usually execute on single thread.
The main objective of this is to improve the performance of the model and reduce the latency.

Comment: When you interoperate with other languages (even if it's through their wrapper packages), you're limited by the other language's implementation and performance.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51318367/scikit-learn-multithreading for multithreading scikitlearn.  In other words, I think you can try using `LogisticRegression(n_jobs=-1)`.

Comment: If you want to give a try to [BetaML](https://github.com/sylvaticus/BetaML.jl), (disclaimer:I'm the author) the `train!` function is multithreaded..